# List View problem

Tags: android, listview

I cannot figure out why it's throwing a NullPointerException on line 28, which is `return mClasses.size();` and I cant figure out why, Any Ideas?

```
private ArrayList<String> mClasses;
    public int size;
    public mAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<String> classes,ArrayList<Integer> checked) {
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        mClasses = classes;
        mChecked = checked;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return mClasses.size();
    }
..etc
}
```

Comment: always add the stack to your question ^^ makes it way faster for other to help.

Comment: Pretty sure mClasses is null there. How do you know it's set before getCount() is called?

Comment: Put that in try catch and log the error. Trace that in adb and put here.

Comment: Sorry to take so long to respond, but now I'm actually having this problem : `12-15 20:40:12.343: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(20357): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 7, size is 7`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is the "classes" your a passing is null.
easily checkable with a

```
if(calsses == null)Log.e("error","parameter classes is null);
```

or launch in debug add a break point on your return and look at the values of the parameters around the breakpoint.

Comment: I had a method that was returning null in a lot of instances that it shouldn't have been, so there's a big problem there, but hardcoding, i was able to make it work, so I've figured out the problem was in a method outside of my `ListView` class, thanks for this idea

Answer (score 0):

```
return this.size();
```

I think.

Comment: hmmm I think getCount returns the size of the list not the size of this, the indentation is misleading but mClasses is just a field here I think

Comment: I've made a more terrible mistake.Sorry for the wrong answer and thank you Jason Rogers.